# Remove master slider admin menu item from wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

I need to remove the Master Slider menu item from the wordpress admin menu.  I have already tried the below but with no luck.

```
function edit_admin_menus() {
  remove_menu_page('master-sliders');
}
add_action( 'admin_menu', 'edit_admin_menus' );
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work for you. I tried it on my end and it works with no problems:

```
function sb_remove_admin_menus(){
    if ( function_exists('masterslider') ) { ?>
        <style type="text/css">
        #toplevel_page_master-slider {
            display: none;
        }       
        </style>
   <?php }
}
add_action('admin_menu', 'sb_remove_admin_menus');
```

Comment: Nothing specific at all. It just doesn't work. I can successfully remove other menus from other plugins so I'm assuming it is the 'master-slider' part that is wrong but I don't know what it should be.

Comment: OK, but you should know that WP "out the box" does not come with any called Master Slider. I'm going to assume you are talking about this plugin: https://wordpress.org/plugins/master-slider/

Comment: Yes that is correct. Sorry, I meant to put that link in my question.

Comment: OK, of you don't want to to appear as a tab in WordPress, then just deactivate the plugin

Comment: Deactivating the plugin will also stop the slideshow on the website.  I just need to remove the tab in the admin area so no one can change anything, not even admins.

Comment: After adding the above code user are getting the following when trying to edit a page - Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /home/username/public_html/wp-content/themes/taunton-vineyard/functions.php:194) in /home/username/public_html/wp-admin/post.php on line 235

Answer (score 0):

See if that resolves.

```
    function sb_remove_admin_menus(){
    if ( current_user_can('editor') ) { ?>
        <style type="text/css">
        #toplevel_page_master-slider {
            display: none;
        }       
        </style>
   <?php }
}
add_action('admin_menu', 'sb_remove_admin_menus');
```